# Filtering DataGridView Binded With DataSet

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need solution how to filtering DGV when is binded to DS. My situation looks that i have DS added from toolbox and in DGV "Properties" i have set datasource and datamember of DS first table. DGV has parent columns from DS and in DGV i making final editing (ex. color column cell, visible false for two columns) for this parent columns. Now i need filtering and when i will change datasource in DGV to on new from BindingSource i will lose all settings added in DGV. How to do this in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter DGV which is binded with DS like this:

```
((DataTable)DataGridViews.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = ColumnName + " like '%" + filterTextFromUser + "%'";;
```

To remove filter u can use following line of code:

```
((DataTable)DataGridViews.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
```